Custom kernel: Stack unaligned, fault on compiler-generated SSE movaps
I'm seeing a weird problem with my kernel where XMM instructions fail as RSP 16 byte alignment constraint is unmet.
The function frame starts with an aligned value but as it makes space for the buffer, it subtracts a number of bytes that isn't a multiple of 16.
In this example the following fragment translates into the following assembly:
json_value * json_parse_ex (json_settings * settings,
                            const json_char * json,
                            size_t length,
                            char * error_buf)
{
   char error [json_error_max];
   const json_char * end;
   json_value * top, * root, * alloc = 0;
   json_state state = { 0 }; //This is the offending instruction
   long flags = 0;
   int num_digits = 0;
   double num_e = 0, num_fraction = 0;
   //More code here
}

The frame at the beggining of the function is:
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffffff6ffecb68:
 rip = 0xffffffff8001d090 in json_parse_ex (/home/norte/bloodmoon/src/util/json.c:258); saved rip = 0xffffffff8001043f
 called by frame at 0xffffffff6ffecb98
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffffff6ffecb58, args: settings=settings@entry=0xffffffff5f9d7170,
    json=json@entry=0xffffffff5f9d7a00 "{\n    \"type\": 11,\n    \"text\": \"Test\",\n    \"resizable\": false,\n    \"x\": 100,\n    \"y\": 100,\n    \"width\": 800,\n    \"height\": 600,\n    \"color\": \"#AA0000\",\n    \n    \"output\": {\n        \"type\": 1,\n        \""..., length=length@entry=798, error_buf=error_buf@entry=0x0
 Locals at 0xffffffff6ffecb58, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffffff6ffecb68
 Saved registers:
  rip at 0xffffffff6ffecb60

The assembly:
   0xffffffff8001d090 <+0>:     endbr64
   0xffffffff8001d094 <+4>:     push   r15
   0xffffffff8001d096 <+6>:     pxor   xmm0,xmm0
   0xffffffff8001d09a <+10>:    push   r14
   0xffffffff8001d09c <+12>:    push   r13
   0xffffffff8001d09e <+14>:    push   r12
   0xffffffff8001d0a0 <+16>:    push   rbp
   0xffffffff8001d0a1 <+17>:    mov    rbp,rcx
   0xffffffff8001d0a4 <+20>:    push   rbx
   0xffffffff8001d0a5 <+21>:    mov    rbx,rsi
   0xffffffff8001d0a8 <+24>:    sub    rsp,0x128
   0xffffffff8001d0af <+31>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x48],0x0
   0xffffffff8001d0b8 <+40>:    movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x50],xmm0
   ; more code here

As the initial RSP is: 0xffffffff6ffecb60 everything seems to conform with the ABI spec. But as you can see, instruction at <+24> preallocates 0x128 bytes on the stack (plus the 6 pushes before), resulting in RSP being: 0xffffffff6ffecb60 - 8*6 - 0x128 = 0xffffffff6ffca08 which is not aligned to 16 Bytes.
Because of this the instruction at <+40> incurs in a General Protection Fault.
¿Any idea on why the compiler would do this? ¡It looks like sabotage to me!
Have a great day (:
P.S. A bit of context:
This code is part of the GUI module of a kernel that i'm developing. https://github.com/TretornESP/bloodmoon We have SIMD and FPU enabled, we save their states with fxsave/fxstor on each context switch. We are running on single core (but SMP is enabled, all non-bsp are just looping atm). We are using preemptive scheduling and right now we are only in DPL 0 (No sysenter/sysexit whatsoever) so processes are kernel tasks and thus before each context switch we change TSS DPL 0 for the BSP to the entering process's stack.
The most probable culprits are the context creation / context switching routines.
CFLAGS ?= -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -pipe -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -std=c11 -ffreestanding -fno-pie -fno-pic -m64 -march=x86-64 -mabi=sysv -mno-80387 -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -MMD
NASMFLAGS ?= -F dwarf -g -f elf64
LDFLAGS ?= -nostdlib -static -z max-page-size=0x1000

GCC -v output:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-13/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2,rust --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-13 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-13-IvzKaI/gcc-13-13.1.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-13-IvzKaI/gcc-13-13.1.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.1.0 (Ubuntu 13.1.0-8ubuntu1~22.04)

Edit 1.
This is the output assembly of hinting the compiler to align.
json_state state __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = {0};

   0xffffffff8001d210 <+0>:     endbr64
   0xffffffff8001d214 <+4>:     push   r15
   0xffffffff8001d216 <+6>:     pxor   xmm0,xmm0
   0xffffffff8001d21a <+10>:    mov    r8,rdi
   0xffffffff8001d21d <+13>:    push   r14
   0xffffffff8001d21f <+15>:    push   r13
   0xffffffff8001d221 <+17>:    push   r12
   0xffffffff8001d223 <+19>:    push   rbp
   0xffffffff8001d224 <+20>:    push   rbx
   0xffffffff8001d225 <+21>:    mov    rbx,rsi
   0xffffffff8001d228 <+24>:    sub    rsp,0x128
   0xffffffff8001d22f <+31>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rcx
   0xffffffff8001d233 <+35>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x48],0x0
   0xffffffff8001d23c <+44>:    movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x50],xmm0

Edit 2: This is my context switch and creation routine ctx
; Inputs:
; RDI: struct task* old
; RSI: struct task* new
; RDX: void* fxsave_area
; RCX: void* fxrstor_area
ctxswtch:
    cli

    ; Push registers rbx, r12, r13, r14, r15
    push rbp
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx
    push r8
    push r9
    push r10
    push r11
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    push r15
    push rsi
    push rdi
    mov rax, cs
    push rax
    mov rax, ds
    push rax
    mov rax, es
    push rax
    mov rax, fs
    push rax
    mov rax, gs
    push rax
    mov rax, ss
    push rax
    pushfq

    ; Save stack pointer in old's rsp_top
    mov qword [rdi + 8], rsp

    ;  save old fpu state
    fxsave [rdx]

    ; Save old's pd
    mov rax, cr3
    mov [rdi + 16], rax

    ; Load new's pd into CR3
    mov rax, [rsi + 16]
    mov cr3, rax

    ; Load new's fpu state into fpu 
    fxrstor [rcx]

    ; Load rsp with new's rsp_top
    mov rsp, qword [rsi + 8]

    ; Pop registers r15, r14, r13, r12, rbx
    popfq
    pop rax
    mov rax, ss
    pop rax
    mov rax, gs
    pop rax
    mov rax, fs
    pop rax
    mov rax, es
    pop rax
    mov rax, ds
    pop rax
    mov rax, cs
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop r15
    pop r14
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop r11
    pop r10
    pop r9
    pop r8
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    pop rbp

    sti
    ret

; RDI stack pointer
; RSI init function
; RDX fxsave_area
ctxcreat:
    cli

    ; Save registers
    push rax
    push rbx
    mov rbx, rsp

    fxsave [rdx]

    mov rsp, [rdi]
    push returnoexit ;This is a dummy stack frame that panics
    push 0x0
    push rsi
    mov rsi, rsp
    add rsi, 0x8
    push rsi
    push 0x98
    push 0x99
    push 0x9A
    push 0x9B
    push 0x88
    push 0x89
    push 0x90
    push 0x91
    push 0x92
    push 0x93
    push 0x94
    push 0x95
    push 0x96
    push 0x97
    mov rax, cs
    push rax
    mov rax, ds
    push rax
    mov rax, es
    push rax
    mov rax, fs
    push rax
    mov rax, gs
    push rax
    mov rax, ss
    push rax
    pushfq
    mov [rdi], rsp
    mov rsp, rbx
    pop rbx
    pop rax

    sti
    ret


Does it work correctly then if you define state with _attribute_ ((aligned (16)))? Not a solution I know, but a harmless workaround maybe. If that works, you may have found a disturbing compiler bug.

Probably worth checking json_state isn't defined with alignment requirement of 8 bytes, though that wouldn't excuse this.

@SimonGoater When I try aligning manually the output of the assembly changes a bit but the issue is still there: See edit

@SimonGoater Also, no other alignment is enforced relevant to this, JSON state is just a struct. This bug happens in every instance of a program prefilling a buffer like this char buff[512] = {0}; the example you see is the smallest.

This might be relevant: https://gcc-bugs.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/Rmku4Ok5/regarding-gcc-emitting-movaps-to-unaligned-memory Here OP relates how a bug in task creation/context switching made the compiler trip. It is way more probable that my code is at fault. Sadly all the moving parts are just too big to post in a SO thread.

The ABI requires RSP to be aligned by 16 before a call, so RSP%16 == 8 on function entry.  (Your code enters the function with RSP%16 == 0, which is the opposite of what GCC is expecting).  The total adjustment to RSP including pushes and sub rsp, imm in the prologue needs to be an odd multiple of 8.  See Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?

If you want to only use 8-byte stack alignment, you could use gcc -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3.  You could also use -mgeneral-regs-only to make it avoid XMM and x87 regs in kernel code, if you don't want to xsaveopt / xrstor for interrupt handlers and system calls, only actual context switches.  That's what Linux does.  (With kernel_fpu_begin() / kernel_fpu_end() around code that uses vector regs, like RAID5 / RAID6.)

Welp, that was dumb on my part, I just padded the stack allocation by 0x8 and it worked. It took me a few weeks and most of my sanity @PeterCordes if you ever want a beer, it is on me!
